# "Facade" vs. "façade"

Tags: word-choice, american-english

I know that both *facade* and *façade* are valid in British English. Is that also true for American English? Or should *facade* be used when writing something for American customers?

This is something that gets used in a Luminaire catalog, and I just stumbled over the French *ç* in the American version.

Comment: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facade) lists both variants -- both are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Google ngrams, ["facade" is far more popular than "façade"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=facade,fa%C3%A7ade&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). So I would just write "facade" unless you want to emphasize the "Frenchness" for stylistic or marketing reasons.

[image: ngram comparison showing facade as far more popular]

Comment: While I agree, it is important to note that those results are generated by computer scanning, which is likely to understand "ç" as "c", which is exactly what happened in this case: http://books.google.com/books?id=YFQCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA280&dq=%22facade%22&hl=en&ei=I426TozwE-PW0QGt-7XeCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CFkQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22facade%22&f=false   (and probably many others)

Comment: Note: "façade" appears in ~1M titles according to google books.

Comment: @Jim: It's true, there will be lots of cases of bad OCR. But I tried searching the Corpus of Contemporary American English and it had zero hits for "façade" so I just went with ngrams.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the "facade" variant has become more popular simply because it's easier to type; one has to jump through hoops in order to access characters containing a cedilla, etc., in my experience at least.

Comment: @paul while I'm sure the accent's absence from typical US English keyboards doesn't help the situation, I think it's also fair to say that most English speakers just don't use accents or other diacritics at all on any words. There are fewer and fewer cases where you could argue that a diacritic is allowed, let alone required. Anglicized words usually drop them and most native speakers are unsure of how to use them. That is the reason why the keyboard doesn't make it easy to write them: they aren't really part of standard English.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 A good point, I had not considered that the trend might predate the keyboard and have influenced its layout. I wonder what data from before the computer era would show?

Comment: Standard (ANSI US) keyboards omit accents because their layout is based on ASCII. The layout of any keyboard (and how easy it is to type accented characters) is purely determined by software. At a hardware level, there are only three types of keyboard in the World (ANSI, ISO and JIS). Each simply emits keyup and keydown events with corresponding keycodes. The OS handles everything from there.

Comment: @CarlSmith Standard keyboards have omitted accents since before computers though.

Comment: Which standard?

Comment: @CarlSmith The QWERTY keyboard layout was a de facto standard in typewriters since the 1880s and it doesn't have accents on it. In some cases some accents could be simulated by overstriking certain symbols over letters, but that's ugly and difficult to do.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 That seems like a positive feedback effect; do keyboards not include accents because writers don't know how to use them or is the public unaware of how to use them because keyboards don't include them?  I would imagine it is both, amplifying one another from the start.

Answer (score 6):

The cedilla (ç) beneath the letter ‘c’ is used in French to show that it is to be pronounced as /s/ and not as /k/. Most French people will know that anyway, so it is as otiose in French as it certainly is in English. Since *facade* is now an English word as much as it is a French one, there’s no need to follow French practice.

Comment: It's no more or less otiose than the other French diacritical marks.  Certainly the first time I read the word I wasn't sure how to pronounce it so the cedilla would have helped.

Comment: It's often difficult to know how to pronounce any new word, with or without diacritics. The answer is available in most dictionaries. Where a French word has not become completely anglicized, then it may be usual to retain the accents, as in, for example, 'dénouement'. The only fully anglicized French word I can think in which the accent is shown more often than not is 'café'.

Comment: You are making unsubstantiated claims about usage.

Comment: [cafe > café](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caf%C3%A9%2Ccafe&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Comment: Alternatively, 'kaff'.

Answer (score 5):

The cedilla helps, imo. Just reading the replies above made me think... hmm... "facade"... hmm, is that faKade? a secret move in fencing?

then I looked for examples that would leave us wondering whether the sound should be "ss" or "k". Thought of "percutant", French for "percussive". 
The plain "c" indicates the need to pronounce correctly: "perKutant". 
And no need to know the word or be familiar with a word to pronounce it correctly. 
No faKade, no perSSutant, all is fine.

Note: I put in two "s" in examples because in French, one "s" only inside a word is often if not most of the time pronounced as /z/ : crise (crisis) pronounced with "z" sound. Bise (greeting kiss) same thing. Mise (placing) same again.

sorry for butting in, these are thoughts that occurred to me as I was passing by. This site was useful, I have bookmarked it. :-) 
A native French-speaker who also loves English.

Comment: In Portuguese we have these rules similar to the French :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, much as people still spell café with an accent. Cafe without the accent just isn´t the same. We all know, French or otherwise, that that last e must be stressed because the accent is there. Otherwise we would just say caff or caif.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need or purpose for using the French cedilla in the English word FACADE. Yes, the French word is, and has been, English for a long time. So it's just a pretension at this point, and functionally unnecessary since we know how to pronounce the word through usage.